# Ping multiple computers through Excel and have IP addresses in a separate column

Tags: excel, vba, automation, ping, system-administration

I need an automatic pinging tool because I have 70 computers in my network and I am sick of pinging them through `cmd` every time. So I have this excel sheet which I have made work (mostly).

**Column A:** contains computer names written manually by me

**Column B:** it should (but doesn't) write out the IP addresses of computers in column A

**Column C:** shows if computer is online or offline based on ping.

**Column D:** Something I put manually as well, to know who sits behind which computer, just usernames.

I have two buttons, `ping` and `stop ping`. They work fine. How can I by pressing the `ping` button, make it go through all the computers in `column A` and show me both their IPs and if they are online or not, all at once?

Of course, it doesn't have to be done through excel, if you have a better solution with great view of all 3 things I need to see clearly (`comp name`, `comp ip`, `online/offline`) and the 4th thing with usernames would be nice to have.

Please help me on this, I am desperate:

```
Dim objshell, boolcode
Set objshell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
boolcode = objshell.Run("ping -n 1 -w 1000 " & strip, 0, True)
If boolcode = 0 Then
    Ping = True
Else
    Ping = False
End If
End Function
'_________________________
Sub PingSystem()
Dim strip As String
Do Until Sheet1.Range("G9").Value = "STOP"
Sheet1.Range("G9").Value = "Ping"
For introw = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(65536, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    strip = ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 2).Value

    If Ping(strip) = True Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 3).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 3).Value = "Online"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 3).Font.Color = RGB(0, 200, 0)
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 3).Font.Color = RGB(200, 0, 0)
        ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 3).Value = "Offline"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If
    If Sheet1.Range("G9").Value = "STOP" Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next
Loop
Sheet1.Range("G9").Value = "Stop ping"
End Sub

Sub stop_ping()
    Sheet1.Range("G9").Value = "STOP"
End Sub
```

[image: image of my excel table]

Comment: You say "Column A: contains computer names written manually by me" but your code `strip = ActiveSheet.Cells(introw, 2).Value` is pinging the value in Column B ?

Comment: That was temporarily there because I first tried to read static IPs. It was changed in the meantime I just forgot to move it from this pasted version. Thank you for noticing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

```
Sub temp()
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To RowCount
    Url = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
    cmd = "ping " + Url
    Set WshShellExec = WshShell.Exec(cmd)
    result = WshShellExec.StdOut.ReadAll
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value = getIP(result)
    
    If (InStr(result, "Received = 4")) Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value = "Online"
    End If
Next
End Sub

Function getIP(result)
    ip = Split(result, vbNewLine)(1)
    startIndex = InStr(ip, "[") + 1
    endIndex = InStr(ip, "]")
    getIP = Mid(ip, startIndex, endIndex - startIndex)
End Function
```

Comment: It adds the IP addresses for each given computer from the A column in every field in the B column? Because to me it does nothing, it only shows that every computer is offline. Where did you put this code you provided exactly?

Comment: Yes, it reads the url from column A, updates the IP address in column B and sets the status in column C. Since I don't have other computers in my network, it was tested with two sample urls - google.com and youtube.com

Comment: It really didn't work for me. How else can I try making it work? Did you put this code below, above or in the middle of what I have posted?

Comment: I did not use your code, but tried it fresh. Altough, when I tried your code now, it worked for me without any changes. Are you able to get the results manually?

Comment: Well then, could you possibly provide me with the whole code? Because what I have and what I added from you can never work together. Or maybe, can you try merging your code with mine somehow? I've been busting my ass here all day ever since you posted it and could not find a solution. I'd really appreciate it. I appreciate what you did so far, you gave me hope that it is possible but I just couldn't get it.

Comment: I don't want them manually. If IP's change in my network, I want to have full surveillance on all of them as well as ping. It doesn't work for me. It just doesn't work. How did you code it, show me the full code please?

Comment: What I have mentioned is the full code. It reads url from column A one by one, pings it and from the ping response retrieves the ip address and the status. Can you share the result of one ping response when you manually try it?

Comment: It doesn't work for me. How do you activate your code? You use developer mode in Excel right? I literally just get an empty B column (the IP column) as a result. I have no response at all.

Comment: For the ping button in your excel worksheet change the function assignment to "temp" function. (Right click on the button -> Assign macro -> select temp function). This will instruct excel to execute the temp function on button click

Comment: The sheet where you have added the data in excel is it named "Sheet1". If not, please rename the sheet to "Sheet1".

Comment: It is sheet1. It doesn't work but I have found another solution. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1):

have a look at Network Tools For Excel, with the Excel add-in you're able to ping multiple IP-addresses from Excel.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).